# How i can sort struct by characters in C?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, data-structures, structure

I used the strategy to sort struct by numbers , but this strategy does not work .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 1000

typedef struct person_{
    char name[100];
    int age;
}person;

void scan_person(person *ptr);
void print_ind(person p);

int name_index_min(person *ptr, int N, int st);

void swap(person *x, person *y);

void sort_name_as(person *ptr, int N);
void sort_name_ds(person *ptr, int N);

int main () {
    person individulas[MAX];
    int n_ind;

    puts("Enter Number of people:");
    scanf("%d",&n_ind);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_ind; i++)
        scan_person(individulas + i);

    printf("\n");

    sort_name_as(individulas,n_ind);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_ind; i++)
        print_ind(individulas[i]); 

    puts("\n");

    sort_name_ds(individulas,n_ind);
    for (int i = 0; i < n_ind; i++)
        print_ind(individulas[i]);   

    printf("\n"); 
      return 0;
}   

void scan_person(person *ptr){

    printf("\nEnter Name & Surename :");
    scanf("\n%99[^\n]", ptr->name);

    printf("Enter Age :");
    scanf ("%d%*c", &(ptr->age));
    printf("\n");
}
void print_ind(person p){
    printf("%s %d  ", p.name, p.age);
}
int name_index_min(person *ptr, int N, int st){

    int min = st;
    for (int i = st+1; i < N; i++)
        if(ptr[i].name < ptr[min].name)
            min = i;
    return min;
}
int name_index_max(person *ptr, int N, int st){

    int max = st;
    for (int i = st+1; i < N; i++)
        if(ptr[i].name > ptr[max].name)
            max = i;
    return max;
}

void swap(person *x, person *y){
    person temp = *x;
    *x = *y;
    *y = temp;
}

void sort_name_as(person *ptr, int N){
    int aux;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++){
        aux = name_index_min(ptr, N, i);
        if (aux != i)
            swap(ptr + i, ptr + aux);
    }
}

void sort_name_ds(person *ptr, int N){
    int aux;
    for (int i = 0; i < N-1; i++){
        aux = name_index_max(ptr, N, i);
        if (aux != i)
            swap(ptr + i, ptr + aux);
    }
}
```

Here is example:

Input:

Enter Number of people:3

Enter Name & Surename :Jeffrey L. Davis
Enter Age :80

Enter Name & Surename :Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury
Enter Age :80

Enter Name & Surename :Joeri Ong
Enter Age :80

Output:

Joeri Ong  80  Jeffrey L. Davis 80  Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury 80  //ascendig order

Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury 80  Jeffrey L. Davis 80  Joeri Ong  80 //descendig order

Comment: I  suggest you use [the standard `qsort` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) with a suitable comparison function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you are faced with a sorting problem in C, you should immediately be thinking `qsort`. It is a highly efficient and flexible sorting function that can handle any type of object that needs sorting. What usually scares new C-programmers away is that you must write a `compare()` function to tell `qsort` how to compare and sort two *pointers to elements* within your array. The prototype for the compare function is:

```
int compare (const void *a, const void *b)
```

All the `a` and `b` pointers are, are pointers to the two elements in your array currently being compared. Your only job is to cast them to the proper type and then tell `qsort` how you want them compared. Let's look at your first function to compare ascending by `age` first, and then if the ages are equal, compare names next so that all patients with the same age are sorted in alphabetical order, start with the prototype:

```
int compasc (const void *a, const void *b)      /* qsort compare ascending by age */
{
```

No know what type your array elements are (`stuct person` here), so `a` and `b` will be of type *pointer-to* `struct person`. Your job is simply to cast the pointers `a` and `b` to type `person*`, e.g.

```
    const person *pa = a, *pb = b;
```

So instead of having `void *` pointers `a` & `b`, you have `person*` pointers `pa` and `pb` to work with in the function. If the ages are different, compare ages and return, e.g.

```
    if (pa->age != pb->age)
        return (pa->age > pb->age) - (pa->age < pb->age);
```

Otherwise, ages are equal so you compare by `name`, e.g.

```
    return (strcmp (pa->name, pb->name));
}
```

That's it for what your compare function needs to be. In full it would be:

```
int compasc (const void *a, const void *b)      /* qsort compare ascending by age */
{
    const person *pa = a, *pb = b;

    if (pa->age != pb->age)
        return (pa->age > pb->age) - (pa->age < pb->age);

    return (strcmp (pa->name, pb->name));
}
```

Compare descending by age operates the same other than for the comparison of `age` which would result in a descending sort on age. Regardless, if the ages are equal, you sort by name in alphabetical order.

You did a good job defining the constant for the max number of `struct person` to use in the array, but you can also declare a constant for the size of `name` as well, e.g.

```
#define MAXNM  100
#define MAXP  1000

typedef struct person {
    char name[MAXNM];
    int age;
} person;
```

(**note:** the `'_'` has been removed from `person_` as POSIX is picky about reserving names that begin/end in underscores -- and there is no need for your struct *tag* and *typdef* name to be different)

In `main()`, you are much better served reading user-input a line-at-a-time using a line-oriented input function like `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()`. This ensures there are no unwanted characters left unread in `stdin` that could bite you on your next attempted read. So just declare a simply character array `buf` to use as a buffer to hold all lines of input. You can then get what you need from the line using `sscanf()` to handle any conversions. To read and store all the data in your array you could do something like:

```
int main (void) {

    int n_ind = 0;
    person individuals[MAXP] = {{ .name = "" }};

    while (n_ind < MAXP) {
        char buf[MAXP] = "";                /* buffer to hold line of input */
        person tmp = { .name = "" };        /* temporary struct to fill */

        fputs ("\nenter name & surname: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXNM, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (*buf == '\n')
            break;

        buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;       /* trim trailing '\n' */
        strcpy (tmp.name, buf);

        fputs ("enter age: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXP, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp.age) == 1)  /* validate age conversion */
            individuals[n_ind++] = tmp;         /* add tmp to array update n_ind */
    }
```

(**note:** `fgets()` also gives you the ability to check whether the first character is the `'\n'` -- allowing you to use an <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone at the `name` prompt as indication that the user is done with input -- you don't need to have them type how many they will enter. You just keep adding names until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone at the `name` prompt.)

Now sorting become trivial with `qsort`, simply pass your array, the number of elements, the size of each element and your compare function you want `qsort` to use, and it does the rest, e.g.

```
    qsort (individuals, n_ind, sizeof *individuals, compasc);   /* sort ascending */
```

That's it for sort-ascending by age -- your `individuals` array is now sorted by age and then by name.

Putting it altogether with both ascending and descending sorts you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXNM  100
#define MAXP  1000

typedef struct person {
    char name[MAXNM];
    int age;
} person;

int compasc (const void *a, const void *b)      /* qsort compare ascending by age */
{
    const person *pa = a, *pb = b;

    if (pa->age != pb->age)
        return (pa->age > pb->age) - (pa->age < pb->age);

    return (strcmp (pa->name, pb->name));
}

int compdesc (const void *a, const void *b)     /* qsort compare descending by age */
{
    const person *pa = a, *pb = b;

    if (pa->age != pb->age)
        return (pa->age < pb->age) - (pa->age > pb->age);

    return (strcmp (pa->name, pb->name));
}

int main (void) {

    int n_ind = 0;
    person individuals[MAXP] = {{ .name = "" }};

    while (n_ind < MAXP) {
        char buf[MAXP] = "";                /* buffer to hold line of input */
        person tmp = { .name = "" };        /* temporary struct to fill */

        fputs ("\nenter name & surname: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXNM, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (*buf == '\n')
            break;

        buf[strcspn (buf, "\n")] = 0;       /* trim trailing '\n' */
        strcpy (tmp.name, buf);

        fputs ("enter age: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (buf, MAXP, stdin))
            return 1;
        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &tmp.age) == 1)  /* validate age conversion */
            individuals[n_ind++] = tmp;         /* add tmp to array update n_ind */
    }

    qsort (individuals, n_ind, sizeof *individuals, compasc);   /* sort ascending */
    puts ("\nascending order by age:");

    for (int i = 0; i  < n_ind; i++)
        printf ("  %-24s    %2d\n", individuals[i].name, individuals[i].age);

    qsort (individuals, n_ind, sizeof *individuals, compdesc);  /* sort descending */
    puts ("\ndescending order by age:");

    for (int i = 0; i  < n_ind; i++)
        printf ("  %-24s    %2d\n", individuals[i].name, individuals[i].age);

}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Sorting by age, an if ages equal, then by name:

```
$ ./bin/individualsbyage

enter name & surname: Jeffrey L Davis
enter age: 80

enter name & surname: Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury
enter age: 80

enter name & surname: Joeri Ong
enter age: 80

enter name & surname:

ascending order by age:
  Jeffrey L Davis             80
  Joeri Ong                   80
  Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury    80

descending order by age:
  Jeffrey L Davis             80
  Joeri Ong                   80
  Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury    80
```

Now a quick example showing that if ages differ, the correct sorts are obtained:

```
$ /bin/individualsbyage

enter name & surname: Jeffrey L Davis
enter age: 81

enter name & surname: Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury
enter age: 80

enter name & surname: Joeri Ong
enter age: 79

enter name & surname:

ascending order by age:
  Joeri Ong                   79
  Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury    80
  Jeffrey L Davis             81

descending order by age:
  Jeffrey L Davis             81
  Yaseen Nur al Din Khoury    80
  Joeri Ong                   79
```

Another benefit with `qsort` beyond it being optimized for a fast sort, it has halso be used and tested by 100,000(s) if not `1,000,000(s) people and validated. (not so for a sort you just happen to cobble together overnight)

Look things over an let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem of your approach is that you are comparing the memory address of the names, instead of the values contained in the arrays.

When you reference an array by name you are actually getting its address. I suggest that you use `strcmp` to compare the `name` arrays on your min/max searching functions.

A quick review of your code revealed that this is the only problem in it.

An implementation of this approach with a slightly simplified input (used `A`, `B` and `C` as the names) is present here: https://onlinegdb.com/r1NkRiNKL.